# What is the C765-Gal4 driver?

Tags: genetics

What is a gene driver and what does C765 stand for? Is Gal4 a transcription factor?

Source: "[Dynamics of Dpp Signaling and Proliferation Control](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/331/6021/1154)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C765 is a transgenic *Drosophila* strain that has a specific Gal4 expression pattern (["embryonic salivary glands and larval wing and leg discs"](http://flystocks.bio.indiana.edu/Reports/36523.html)).

Gal4 is a transcription factor from yeast which binds an upstream activating sequence (UAS) and also happens to function in other species (like flies). In the [Gal4/UAS system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAL4/UAS_system), a strain expressing Gal4, under the control of a tissue specific promoter or a minimal promoter in an [enhancer trap](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhancer_trap), is crossed with a strain expressing a gene of interest flanked at the 5' end by the UAS. The F1 generation will thus express the gene of interest tissue specifically (ie only in the tissue(s) expressing Gal4).

[image]

[[source](http://www.fly-trap.org/flytrap/html/docs/egal4.html)]

---

Further reading:

[Phelps CB, Brand, AH. 1998. Ectopic Gene Expression in *Drosophila* Using Gal4 System. Methods 14(4):367-379.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1046202398905928?via%3Dihub)